# How to convert API call to json/python script

Tags: python, json, api

Here is the API, that I have to convert to `.py` script `POST` call:

```
<url>../json?<param1>=<value>&<param2>=<value>&<param3>=[{"x": "y", "1": "2"}, {"a":"b", "s":"1"}]
```

What I've tried:

```
import requests
import json
r = {'param1':'value', 'param2':'value', 'param3':{"x": "y", "1": "2"}}
r = requests.post('<url>../json', data=r)
```

I'm not sure how to include `{"a": "b", "s": "1"}`, but it actually doesnt work even with one `{"x": "y", "1": "2"}` because it is posting all correct until `<param3>` where it is just set for value `"1"`.

i see that it was marked as duplicate, but if I try:

```
import json
import requests
url = '<url>/json'
payload = {"param3": {"x": "y", "1": 2"}} 
data = json.dumps(payload) 
headers = {'param1':'value', 'param2':'value'} 
requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
```

It is not posting anything, on my first try at least it is posting, even wrong. In the rules is said to open new question if the answer for the duplicate doesnt help. Please delete if it is against the rules. But my question is still unaswered

Comment: Why are you dumping the dictionary to a string? Just include it directly.

Comment: Are you saying you want `[{"x": "y", "1": "2"}, {"a":"b", "s":"1"}]` literally embedded into the query string?

Comment: If so, what's the point of doing a POST?

Comment: It looks like your API is expecting a query string and you are trying to send it POST data. Maybe try requests.get() instead of requests.post()

Comment: I am trying post because I am told I have to do it with POST but not with GET, it is because we are allowed to insert a lot of params in param3{} and maybe GET will not handle all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me (taken straight from their [website](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)):

```
import requests

payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
r = requests.post("http://httpbin.org/post", data=payload)
```

Comment: It works, thank you, it was config file that I am using with wrong server parameters

Answer (score 0):

The API that you've described passes the parameters in the query string, not in the POST body (not sure what the point of using POST over GET is then, but whatever).  The way to do this is:

```
params = {
    'param1':'value',
    'param2':'value',
    # Note that query parameter values are strings, so you need to serialize this one:
    'param3': json.dumps({"x": "y", "1": "2"})
}
r = requests.post('<url>../json', params=params)
```

Comment: Thank you. This version is trying to post, but is not posting maybe in the correct order or something, because the changes made does not taking efect. It should do the same as APY call:
    <url>../json?<param1>=<value>&<param2>=<value>&<param3>=[{"x": "y", "1": "2"}, {"a":"b", "s":"1"}]

also how can I include the ` {"a":"b", "s":"1"}` partt? with , ?
maybe something like  `'param3': json.dumps({"x": "y", "1": "2"},{"a":"b", "s":"1"})